# How to establish WebAPI for Amazon RDS SQL Database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, xamarin, aws-sdk

I am working on Xamarin Mobile App for which we are using SQL 2012 as Server Database. DB is already hosted in Amazon RDS. However, I am not clear on creating WebApi for the database.

How to establish WebAPI for Amazon RDS SQL Database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I DO suggestion to create an API as this can serve as the interface between your database and your Xamarin Mobile App.

You could use AWS Elastic Beanstalk for the hosting. [This guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.html) shows you wow to work with .Net and RDS and later be able to deploy it on Amazon.

Comment: Yes, I need API. I got stuck in that part. Now, AWS Elastic Beanstalk is talking more about Web Applications. I am not sure, whether any new code has to be written to build the API connecting to SQL Instance in the AWS